# Dynamic sheets reference + column ranges using only column number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple sheets simply named "2019", "2021", "2021".
In each of those, I have columns whose first cell contains a currency code: "EUR", "XRP", "XBT", etc.

Now I wanna create a new sheet in which a dynamic formula would take a **year** and a **currency code** as inputs and find the *last filled value* of the columnt starting with this currency code on the sheet named with the inputed year.

I can find the column number using MATCH(D5;'2021'!$1:$1;0), where D5 contains my currency code, but I don't know how to make the sheet name dynamic (say I write 2021 in cell A1 on my new sheet, how do I put A1 in this formula instead).

I can find the last value of column O using OFFSET('2021'!O1;COUNTA('2021'!O:O)-1;0) but I wanna use the column number found previously instead.

I'm scratching my head over this, any help would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution but these are the functions involved:

Example:
A1=INDIRECT(A2&"!C1")
A2="2021"

Using the INDIRECT-Function you would build the reference path for your value.

"last filled value" is not precise.
If you fill the values in chronological order this is most likely the lowest one in a column.
If your column setup includes a date you could look up the most recent date using the MAX-function over the date column. You would then adress the value using Vlookup using the result of the MAX-function as a key.

Calculate that figure on designated fields like B1, D1 and F1 on each yearly sheet. Then, depending on the currency searched, build the formula to point to either B1, D1 or F1.

Comment: my values are in chronological order already, the last ones are the most recent

Comment: `COUNTA()` or its siblings will tell how many cells has data in a column or row. Use it as argument to `OFFSET()` on a cell reference to find e.g. the last item in a list / rows / columns,  WHEN / IF you find a way to do what you want, then I suggest you also create an "answer" below.

Comment: Hint: `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style`